# Como conectar uma Storage Account do Azure em um projeto ASP.NET Core?

Tags: microsoft-azure, asp.net-core

Estou utilizando VS2017 com ASP.NET Core 2.0 (template Angular) e preciso fazer as operações básicas de CRUD baseada em tables no Azure Storage.

Existe alguma maneira de fazer scaffold no meu ambiente?

Comment: Existe uma ferramenta no Visual Studio Marketplace que pode te ajudar a fazer Scaffold do Azure Storage Tables.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=StephanJohnsonBlueMarble.AzureTableStorageScaffolder

Comment: Infelizmente não tem pro VS2017... só pro 2013, então acredito que não tenha como fazer com essa extensão usando .NET Core

Comment: Acho que não! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infelizmente não tem nenhuma forma conectar uma Storage Account do Azure via Connected Services usando qualquer versão e layout do ASP.NET Core (pelo menos no Visual Studio 2017), entretanto, existe uma maneira manual de fazer essa ponte, seguem os passos que utilizei para resolver o problema:

Primeiramente, precisei instalar o pacote NuGet [`WindowsAzure.Storage`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage).

Na minha pasta `Models`, criei uma classe `Foo` que representava o modelo da minha table do Azure. Todos as classes de modelo herdam de `TableEntity`, que tem aquelas propriedades básicas para todas as tables do Azure: `PartitionKey`, `RowKey`, `ETag`, etc.

```
public class Foo : TableEntity {
  public string FooField { get; set; }
  public string FooField2 { get; set; }  
}
```

Criei uma pasta `Repositories` na raiz do projeto e adicionei uma classe `FooRepository`, para manipulação das tables (CRUD)

```
public class FooRepository {

  private readonly CloudStorageAccount storageAccount { get; }

  public FooRepository(string connectionString) {
    storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
  }

  public Task<IEnumerable<Foo>> GetAsync() {
    // ...
  }

  public Task<Foo> GetAsync(string partitionKey, string rowKey) {
    // ...
  }

  public Task UpdateAsync(string partitionKey, string rowKey, Foo updatedEntity) {
    // ...
  }

  public Task DeleteAsync(string partitionKey, string rowKey) {
    // ...
  }

  public Task CreateAsync(Foo newEntity) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

O `FooRepository` foi referenciado no meu `FooController`, que ficou mais ou menos dessa forma:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Foo")]
public class FooController : Controller {
    readonly FooRepository repo = new FooRepository("connectionString");

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<List<Foo>> Get() {
        return (await repo.GetEntitiesAsync()).Item1;
    }       
}
```

A string de conexão pode ser encontrada no portal do Azure. Pode passá-la como eu fiz, a cada vez que referenciar um `Repository`, ou colocá-la em um arquivo estruturado como *.xml ou *.json e ler de forma fixa, tirando o `connectionString` do construtor dos repositories, que é uma prática que eu recomendo, já que essas strings de conexão podem mudar eventualmente (DRY!).

---

Um `Repository` pode ser mais abstrato, como fiz no exemplo abaixo:

```
public class BaseRepository<T> : IRepository where T : class, ITableEntity, new() {

    CloudStorageAccount IRepository.StorageAccount { get; set; }
    CloudTableClient IRepository.TableClient { get; set; }
    CloudTable IRepository.Table => ((IRepository)this).TableClient.GetTableReference(nameof(T));

    public BaseRepository(string connString) {
        ((IRepository) this).StorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connString);
        ((IRepository) this).TableClient = ((IRepository) this).StorageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
    }

    public Task CreateAsync(T entity) {
        TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(entity);
        return ((IRepository) this).Table.ExecuteAsync(insertOperation);
    }

    public async Task<T> GetEntityAsync(string partitionKey, string rowKey) {
        TableOperation retrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<T>(partitionKey, rowKey);

        T entity = (await ((IRepository)this).Table.ExecuteAsync(retrieveOperation)).Result as T;
        return entity;
    }

    public async Task<Tuple<List<T>, TableContinuationToken>> GetEntitiesAsync(TableContinuationToken token = null) {
        List<T> list = new List<T>();
        TableQuery<T> query = new TableQuery<T>().Take(15);

        TableQuerySegment<T> tableQueryResult = await ((IRepository)this).Table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, token);
        list.AddRange(tableQueryResult.Results);

        return Tuple.Create(list, tableQueryResult.ContinuationToken);
    }

    public async Task<T> DeleteEntityAsync(string partitionKey, string rowKey) {
        T entityToDelete = await GetEntityAsync(partitionKey, rowKey);

        TableOperation deleteOperation = TableOperation.Delete(entityToDelete);
        await ((IRepository)this).Table.ExecuteAsync(deleteOperation);

        return entityToDelete;
    }
}
```

Sendo `IRepository` uma interface simples:

```
interface IRepository {
    CloudStorageAccount StorageAccount { get; set; }
    CloudTableClient TableClient { get; set;  }
    CloudTable Table { get; }
}
```

Veja que o `GetEntitiesAsync(TableContinuationToken)` só está pegando 15 resultados, quando o usuário passar a página, você chama o método passando o token retornado. Mais detalhes sobre a manipulação podem ser lidos [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-dotnet).

Answer (score 2):

## Azure Storage Emulator

Primeiro você deve configurar o emulador de Azure Storage localmente, assim poderá desenvolver sem a necessidade de ir remoto.

O emulador de armazenamento está disponível como parte do [Microsoft Azure SDK](https://azure.microsoft.com/downloads/). Voce também pode instalar o emulador de armazenamento individualmente ([download aqui](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=717179&clcid=0x409)).

Após instalar, basta executar o aplicativo **Azure Storage Emulator**, selecionar o tipo que deseja emular e pronto.

## Azure Storage Explorer

Para ajudar, vc também poder usar o Azure Storage Explorer para tornar mais amigável seu consumo dos armazenamento - seja no Azure, ou seja [localmente](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer#work-with-local-development-storage).

[image: Azure Storage Explorer]

[Baixe o Azure Storage Explorer aqui](http://www.storageexplorer.com/).

**Fontes:**

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-emulator-using
https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator